# Unit test for callback function in angularJs using jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

How to unit test a callback function using jasmine.

```
let somefunctionCallback = function (error, response) {
  if (!error) {
    $('.loading').hide();
    $scope.infomsg = response.data.message;
    $scope.showInfoMsg();
    $timeout(vm.hideInfoMsg, 3000);

    someFactory.getTestList('avList', $scope.tokenId, vm.someotherCallback);
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you show how this function is used?